# How to transfer files between local machine and minikube?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, boot2docker, minikube

I am using OS Ubuntu 16.0.4 and i installed minikube on it.
I need to copy some files to minikube, so how can i do that?
I tried next command but it asked me on password and i don't know it

```
scp /media/myuser/sourceFolder docker@192.168.99.100:/home/docker/destiationFolder
```

**Note:** minikube IP is **192.168.99.100**, and i used **docker** as default user for minikube but actually i don't know if it correct ot not.

So what is the default username and password for minikube and how can i copy files from my local machine into minikube?

Thanks :)

Comment: The private key for accessing your minikube machine I believe is located at `~/.minikube/machines/*/id_rsa` (the `docker` user in boot2docker does not have a password to my knowledge)

Comment: As a follow-up, at least in `minikube` v0.21.0, there is a dedicated `minikube ssh-key` command that will output the path to `id_rsa` (it's exactly where I said it would be, but `minikube ssh-key` is likely the more portable way to get that path)

Comment: Easy way out: minikube mounts the user home folder by default. In my case, I'm running minikube on Windows 10 via VirtualBox and my c:\Users folder is mapped to /c/Users folder inside the minikube VM.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I handled it by following next steps:

1- going into ssh of minikube >> **`minikube ssh`**

2- Changing docker password using sudo >> **`sudo passwd docker`** and create new password so now i know docker user password

3- exit from ssh and go back to Ubuntu terminal >> **`exit`**

4- using scp command to copy files into minikube >> **`scp /local/path/to/file/ docker@minikubeIp:/your/destination/folder/`**

For example **`scp -r /media/myuser/sourceFolder docker@192.168.99.100:/home/docker`**

and after that it asked only for minikube docker user password which i know it now after changed it then write password and folders copied successfully into minikube from local machine

Comment: Just an addition, you can skip changing the password for the 'docker' user on minikube, by using the access key :

     scp -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -r /folder2copy 
     docker@192.168.99.100:/home/docker

Comment: in the version of scp I have I don't see a -i option

Comment: i get connection refused

Comment: @HappyMachine Sorry, could you plz share the command which result was connection refused?

Answer (score 51):

On the host machine you can use the `ssh-key` and `ip` subcommands of the `minikube` command:

```
scp -i $(minikube ssh-key) <local-path> docker@$(minikube ip):<remote-path>
```

So the command from the question becomes:

```
scp -i $(minikube ssh-key) /media/myuser/sourceFolder docker@$(minikube ip):/home/docker/destiationFolder
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to document where this should be run, in case user already shelled into minikube and wants to scp from there (and vice versa).

Comment: I tried `scp -i $(minikube ssh-key) ~/.docker/config.json docker@$(minikube ip):/var/lib/kubelet/config.json`, but I received a ***Permission denied*** error  .

Comment: I'm getting the following error, any idea where it could come from?
`ssh: connect to host 192.168.49.2 port 22: Operation timed out
lost connection`

Comment: I ran `PS C:\Users\REDACTED> scp -i $(minikube ssh-key) "C:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\REDACTED.sql" docker@$(minikube ip):/var/opt/mssql` but got back:

`ssh: connect to host REDACTED port 22: Connection timed out`

Answer (score 4):

you can use `kubectl cp` command. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp

Comment: As a small nit, I believe the question was about copying to the minikube machine itself, and not into any specific Pod. However, your command is 100% accurate for getting files into running Pods

Comment: I agree with @MatthewLDaniel that kubectl is fine for copying files into pods but not in minikube machine itself, so this command will not work and you can test it yourself

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood the question.  Usally I ran the pods inside the minikube.   May I know the use case to copy files to minikube?

Comment: @sfgroups to know the use case to copy files to minikube? please check my answer, i wrote the steps to do that, hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 4):

At minikube 1.7, if using the VirtualBox driver, there exists a  `/hosthome` folder mounted inside the minikube VM. This is a VirtualBox shared folder mapping to `/home` of the host system.

So, practically, if you ssh to the minikube VM everything from your home folder is readable and you can use normal `cp` commands to copy things around.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `minikube cp` to copy the specified file into minikube.

```
minikube cp <source file path> <target node name>:<target file absolute path> [flags]
```

If you don't know the target node name, you can run `minikube node list` first to get the node name. More info could be found in the [official doc](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/cp/).

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed minikube Windows Host then you can find the ssh public & private keys for docker user (docker user is in the minikube vm) 
in

```
C:\Users\{yourusername}\.minikube\machines\minikube
```

on Windows Host.

The files are copied by minikube.exe during vm creation.

The files are id_rsa & id_rsa.pub.

Then open the id_rsa in puttygen and save the private key in .ppk format.

After that you can use the newly saved private key with Winscp.

Host name: ip-address of you minikube vm  { can get it with c:\minikube ip }

username: docker

port : 22

Go to Advanced ---> Advanced ----> SSH ----> Authentication ---->private key file

Then open...

Answer (score 1):

On my M1 MacBook, the copying solution from [@Drik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343921/dirk) did not work as expected, while getting some errors like:

```bash
ssh: connect to host 192.168.49.2 port 22: Operation timed out lost connection
```

> Sidenote: atm of writing the only way to I was able to run the minikube correctly on AppleSilicon macs is via minikube + docker driver.

I come across [this post](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14902) where @afbjorklund stated.

> "Unfortunately Docker Desktop does not offer direct access to the VM, unlike other drivers."

Although there is an option to connect via docker hidden tunneled port.

#### Solution (minikube + docker driver)

I puzzled all this together and finally managed to copy files also on M1 using minikube + docker driver

```
$ docker port <CONTAINER_ID>
22/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:58408
2376/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:58409

scp -i $(minikube ssh-key) -P 58408 /media/myuser/sourceFolder docker@127.0.0.1:/home/docker/destiationFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to copy required files/folders to minikube machine.

```
minikube ssh
sudo su root
scp -r <user>@<ip address of linux machine>:<SOURCE FOLDER PATH> <DESTINATION FOLDER PATH>
scp -r user@192.145.34.23:/home/userhome/sourfolder /etc/destinationfolder
Enter password of linux machine
```

Answer (score 0):

As som answers have already mentioned, you can [mount a local directory onto Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/):
`minikube mount <source directory>:<target directory>`

This is supremely useful as you can move files in either direction, and use it to easily inspect the outputs of any work done inside Minikube.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, the easiest way would be to -

`minicube cp <source-file> <absolute-path/target-file>`