# How can I install / use tcpdump on minikube?

Tags: minikube

I'm trying to investigate a network issue and would like to install tcpdump / tshark.

What package manager does minikube use? How can I install tcpdump?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not an easy task.

Minikube VM is based on [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) distribution.

Usually minikube [uses docker](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/contributors/build_guide.md) to build a buildroot image, but you can [clone buildroot repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/Makefile#L126) and configure it to include [tcpdump package](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/master/package/tcpdump/) using specific targets (make iso-minikube, make iso-menuconfig).

Then you need to [build](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/contributors/minikube_iso.md) a minikube image and run minikube using that image.
The manual is not full, but gives you the main idea of what to do.

Alternatively you may try to [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086303/how-to-transfer-files-between-local-machine-and-minikube) `tcpdump` and all its dependencies to minikube VM using `scp`.

Answer (score 4):

I would run a container with my favorite os and use host network then install tcpdump inside the container

```
minikube$docker run --network host -it ubuntu
ubuntu#apt update && apt install tcpdump
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the fastest way is using static tcpdump binary.

You can run this on minikube

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yunchih/static-binaries/master/tcpdump -o tcpdump
chmod +x ./tcpdump
```

And now you can use it as a regular tcpdump

```
sudo ./tcpdump ...
```

PS.
I don't recommend using random binaries from internet due to security reasons.

Preferably, compile it yourself from source as a static binary and then use it.