# How do you get a package manager in the Minikube VM (KVM2)?

Tags: minikube, kvm, buildroot

I've created a simple kubernetes cluster with minikube using `minikube start --driver=kvm2` and then ssh'd into the VM with `minikube ssh`.

I'm using a volume mount between the minikube VM and some pods so that I can share a large dataset. However, I need to install python to download this dataset (onto the VM). Normally I would use `apt-get` to install python, but the VM does not have this installed. I can't install `apt-get` using `dpkg` either, because `dpkg` also doesn't exist.

The output of `uname -r` is `4.19.114` and the output of `cat /etc/os-release` is:

```
NAME=Buildroot
VERSION=2019.02.11
ID=buildroot
VERSION_ID=2019.02.11
PRETTY_NAME="Buildroot 2019.02.11"
```

Does anybody know how I install a package manager inside the VM?

Comment: Did you try to mount the local directory which contains those files into minikube (using `minikube mount`) ?

Comment: I've tried that in the past, but it doesn't work well with a large dataset. As the minikube website says about [9P Mounts](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/), they don't work well with a large number of files. I ended up switching to `virtualbox` as my driver, which mounts the `/home` folder to `/hosthome` inside the VM.

Comment: @LukeThistlethwaite did you ever figure out how to get a package manager inside the VM?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to have custom configuration with the minikube image but that would require to configure the image.  This [document](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/contrib/building/iso/) show how to build the image and modify buildroot components.  You can add kernel modules or some third-party packages. You might also want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747069/how-can-i-install-use-tcpdump-on-minikube) case whereas tcpdump is need into minikube image.

Alternative way to to have mount the files using the `minikube mount`:

```
minikube mount <source directory>:<target directory>
```

or use one of the local driver mounts (KVM does not support this at the moment):

> | Virtualbox  | Linux   | /home | /hosthome
>
> | Virtualbox  | macOS   | /Users | /Users
>
> | Virtualbox  | Windows   | C://Users | /c/Users |
>
> | VMware Fusion  | macOS   | /Users | /Users

Third option is to use [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

> Specialized containers that run before app containers in a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/). Init containers can contain utilities or setup scripts not present in an app image.

You can use init container to pre-populate some volume with data you require for your pod/deployment.  Here is a good [document](https://dev.to/jmarhee/getting-started-with-kubernetes-initcontainers-and-volume-pre-population-j83) that shows how to do that.